# javascript: Multiple clickable sprites

Tags: javascript, button, sprite, phaser-framework

I'm creating a web game using JavaScript with phaser. I'm used to Java and have a hard time grasping the proper way to build my simple button-based game. The game is a simple map of every landscape of sweden. The game content is to be changed depending on which landscape I press. Elements to be updated could be Button titles, Text data etc.

One problem I encountered by generating many Landscape classes is that m last created landscape overwrites the others. The console should write the name of the pressed landscape, but pressing every landscape generates the name of my last created landscape object.

Looking over my solution, not really getting it the way I want it, I'm wondering if I look the my game structure in a wrong way.

Is there a better way to do this?

Here is a link of what the game currently looks like: http://postimg.org/image/l5jthna4x/

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var game = new Phaser.Game(480, 700, Phaser.AUTO, '', { preload: preload, create: create, update: update });

function create() {
    game.stage.backgroundColor = '#7dc3ff';

    sweden(0, 0, 'sweden', 10000000);

    var btnLand = new BtnLand();
    btnLand.changeText("Sweden");

}

function update() {

}

function render() {

}


var BtnLand = function (){ 
    this.btn = game.add.sprite(game.world.centerX, game.world.height, 'btn-main');
    this.btn.scale.setTo(0.8, 1);
    this.btn.anchor.set(0.5, 1)
    this.btn.inputEnabled = true;
}

BtnLand.prototype.changeText = function (title) {
    this.title = title;
    var style = { font: "32px Arial", fill: "#000000", wordWrap: true, wordWrapWidth: this.width, align: "center" };
    this.text = game.add.text(this.btn.x, this.btn.y, this.title, style);
    this.text.anchor.set(0.5, 1.5);
}


var Landscape = function(x, y, name) {
    this.landname = name;

    this.area = game.add.sprite(x, y, this.landname);
    this.area.anchor.set(0.5);

    this.area.inputEnabled = true;
    this.area.events.onInputDown.add(listener, this);

}

var sweden = function(x, y, name) {
    this.smaland = Landscape(230 + x, 483 + y, 'smaland', 720358);
    this.skane = Landscape(200 + x, 600 + y, 'skane', 1289000);
    this.blekinge = Landscape(277 + x, 565 + y, 'blekinge', 152315);
    this.halland = Landscape(127 + x, 505 + y, 'halland', 152315);

}


function listener () {
    console.log("pressed " + landname);
    btnLand.changeText(landname);
}

</script>
```

I appreciate all the advice I can get!

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main issue would be calling `Landscape` as a function and not as a constructor.

If you change each of the `Landscape` calls to `new Landscape` you will create 4 separate landscapes and the scope for `this` will be the object rather than the global scope.